# Swig : How to get an "output" integer in Java and not an "array"?

Tags: java, arrays, output, swig

I intend to get in Java `int a_output`, so I do the following :

**sample.h** :

```
void fooA(int *a_output);
```

**sample.i** :

```
%module sample
%{
   #include "sample.h"
%}
%include "typemaps.i"
%apply int *OUTPUT { int *a_output };

%include "sample.h"
```

But in Java I get an array : `int[] a_output`

How should I modify my Swig interface to get `int` instead? Because this is the output of the function fooA and not an array...

Thank you a lot!

**EDIT :**

It might be a bad idea to convert the argument into `int a_output` in Java if it will expire outside `fooA`function. So, I need your advices as well about the best form to convert it into in Java..

Comment: This is java? Looks like C/C++/Obj-C to me.

Comment: @MikeKoch Swig is a JNI generator to interact between C++ and Java (and other languages).

Comment: haven't seen keyword java in the list of supported by swig languages

Comment: @GáborBakos ah gotcha. Guess you learn something new every day!

Comment: @nikpon It is there: http://www.swig.org/compare.html

Comment: In Java you cannot have output variables, so you need the array to get the value, or better yet, you can define a data type that can get the result from the output and fill the result from C++. Would this work for you?

Comment: Can you explain why `int fooA()` is not applicable to your situation?